# Change tab bar width for pages in VIM

Tags: vim, tabs

I usually work with a lot of pages at the same time in VIM, and some of them are less relevant than others. Is it possible to adjust the width of some tabs, like the "pin tab" feature in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [taboo.vim](https://github.com/gcmt/taboo.vim) plugin to change a tab label. Once it's installed, run:

```
:TabooRename <tabname>  " auto-adjusts the tab's width
```

You can also use the [`tabline`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27tabline%27) option. This is more complicated, since you need a single expression that includes labels for all the open tabs. See [`setting-tabline`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#setting-tabline) for a complete example.

To move a tab to the beginning of the tab list use `:tabmove 0`.

Comment: I'm seeing the dev page but I can't see any option to change tab width. Is there any option to do this? It's nice to be able to change the name of a tab and thank you for suggesting this plugin, but it's not really what I need. Another option would be allowing a second row of tabs.

Comment: When you rename a tab, its width is automatically adjusted. So it's basically the same as if you change the width.

Comment: You are right. I'll try this tomorrow and will let you know. Thank you!